# Corrupted ApplicationHost.config

Tags: windows, iis-8

I'm trying to migrate our IIS6 website to IIS8. when I have all the applications, virtual directories and application pools configured. I start to test diferent configurations and suddendly IIS throw a xml malformed error in applicationhost.config. When I compare the file woth the backup I can see that all quotation marks are removed from the file.

Comment: So...put them back?

Comment: Tell us how you did the migration.

Comment: I can do a rollback from the IIS history but I need to know why happens. I re-created the site in IIS8 and imported web.config using APPCMD. The site works correctly but in some moments the application or administration.config get corrupted